# Saving the captured traffic of tcpdump after 24 hours

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I'm currently setting up multiple Linux Servers in order to build a honeypot infrastructure. I want to capture the incoming and outgoing traffic with `tcpdump` too. Is it possible to save the captured traffic of the last 24 hours as a `pcap`-file (i.e. every day at midnight)?

Comment: Why do you want this by time period? The better process would be to save them by size ....

Comment: The feature to create a new pcap file after a while is built into tcpdump. Just have a look at the [man page](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) and look for the word "rotate".

Comment: Didn't found this functionality. Thanks.